# C2780 al usar el algoritmo copy de la STL

Tags: c++, c++11

Saludos,
estoy probando a diseñar un "copy constructor", todo iba bien hasta que se me ocurrió usar el algoritmo copy y he obtenido un C2780 pues al parecer solo reconoce 2 de 3 argumentos para copy...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

// a very simplified vector of doubles
class vector {
    int sz; // the size
    double* elem; // a pointer to the elements
public:
    vector(int s) :sz{ s }, elem{ new double[s] } 
    { for (int i = 0; i<sz; ++i) elem[i] = 0.0; } // constructor
    vector(const vector&); // copy constructor: define copy
    ~vector() { delete[] elem; } // destructor
    int size() const { return sz; } // the current size
    double get(int n) const { return elem[n]; } // access: read
    void set(int n, double v) { elem[n] = v; } // access: write
};

vector::vector(const vector& arg)
// allocate elements, then initialize them by copying
    :sz{ arg.sz }, elem{ new double[arg.sz] }
{
    copy(arg, arg + sz, elem); // std::copy(); see §B.5.2
}

int main()
{
    vector v(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v.set(i, 1.1*i);
        cout << "v[" << i << "]==" << v.get(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que la funcion copy que estas intentado utilizar recibe como parametros 2 iteradores/apuntadores al array que quieres copiar, por lo tanto debes de pasar el apuntador al inicio del arreglo y al final, con lo cual debería quedar así

Edit. Versión marcada como obsoleta al utilizar punteros:

```
copy( arg.elem, arg.elem + arg.sz, elem );
```

solo funciona con iteradores vector, list, map, etc.

Alternativa que no te marcara el error de deprecated:

```
memcpy( elem, arg.elem, sizeof( double ) * arg.sz );
```

Aquí es `sizeof( double ) * arg.sz` a diferencia de la funcion anterior, ya que se estan copiando bytes en lugar de elementos.

Comment: La verdad es que la cosa mejora, pero ahora el C4996 me dice que los parámetros pueden no ser seguros.

Comment: Es verdad, una disculpa por no haber probado el codigo olvide que esa función es obsoleta para arreglos con punteros. Voy a editar el codigo para dejarte una solución que te sirva.

Comment: ¡Muy amable! es que tengo varios ejemplos de código fuente anteriores a C++11 y me hago un lío ^^! pero claro nunca se sabe cuando te vas a encontrar una aplicación antigua y me interesa saber algo del "viejo estilo"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `arg` es de tipo "vector", no es el puntero a double que esperas.

Otro problema adicional es que no deberías usar el nombre "vector" para tipos propios junto con "using namespace std;"; realmente, no está nada bien.

La línea en cuestión debería verse como:

```
std::copy(arg.elem, arg.elem + sz, elem);
```